# Pandas Suppress Message on Opening HDF5 File

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

When I open some HDF5 files using pandas, it displays a message:

> Opening /path/to/file/file_name.h5 in read-only mode

How can I suppress this message? Note that I don't always get it; when I tried to make a test example below, I can read it in with no message:

```
pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]}).to_hdf('test.h5', 'key', mode='w')
_ = pd.read_hdf('test.h5')
```

I don't know if it's the size of the the file that matters? The one I use in practice is much larger than the test file created above.

EDIT:
I created a large test file, and I still don't get the message when reading it:

```
# don't run this if you don't want a 1G dummy file
pd.DataFrame({ch: np.arange(10000000) for ch in 'abcdefghijklm'}).to_hdf('test.h5', 'k1')
_ = pd.read_hdf('test.h5', 'k1')
```

I didn't create the file that gives me the message myself, so I'm not sure if there are certain flags that could be set when calling `pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf()` that might cause this message to always appear when reading the file?

Comment: The message is printed by `../pandas/io/pytables.py`.  It seems pytables has raise an `IOError` and pandas just print this message.  Someone has filed an issue to pandas ([detail issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12106)).  The only way to stop it from printing is set a mode during open the file.  Otherwise you need to look for a way to stop it output the message to `stdout`.

Comment: @SSC if you want to add that as an answer, I'll go ahead and accept it. Passing in `mode='r'` works well enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This message displays if you have a read-only HDF5 file but don't open it in read mode (as a warning that you won't be able to write to the file, which you might normally expect to be able to do).

To avoid this message, open your file as:

```
pd.read_hdf('test.h5', mode='r')
```